# How can I render the name of the user that has logged in with facebook login?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, passport.js

I implemented Facebook login using Passport.js. It works correctly on the backend and introduces the id and name in the database. The problem is that I can't find how to display the name in my react component.

A friend helped me write this axios call but it didn't work. Is there anything else I can try?

```
return axios ({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/user',
        params: {},
        withCredentials: true
    }).then(result => {
      this.setState({ user: result.data }, () => {
          console.log("does this work?", result);
      });
    });
```

Here is the backend passport code

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: 1227008554140703,
        clientSecret: secrets.facebookSecret,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:8080/facebook/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile);
        return database.findOrCreateFacebookUser(profile.id, profile.displayName).then((user) => {
            console.log("user here", user);
            done(null, user)
        })
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serialize", user);
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("deserialize");

    return database.getFacebookUser(id).then(user => {
        done(null, user);
    });
});


app.get('/user',
    (req, res) => {
        res.json(req.user);
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `console.log("does this work?", result)` outputting?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you omitted the credentials in the request. It should be something like this:

```
return axios ({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/user',
        params: {},
        withCredentials: true,
        auth: {
           username: 'myusername',
           password: 'mypassword'
        }
    }).then(result => {
      this.setState({ user: result.data }, () => {
          console.log("does this work?", result);
      });
    });
```

also, try to catch for errors in that request and log the possible error.

Then, maybe put that " console.log("does this work?", result);" above the setState just to be clearer